# Unable to update array of object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose

I tried to update a field in an array of objects but it doesn't work despite I followed the official documentation of mongoose:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Here is the array of the objects:

[image]

And here is the query to update:

```
// Complete Task :
router.put("/completetask/:id/:index", (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id, "tasks.index":Number(req.params.index) },
    { $set: { "tasks.$.isCompleted": true } },
  )
    .then((user) => res.send(user))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: Can you try the `findOne` and post it. Because `findOneAndUpdate` should find something to update.

Comment: the idea is to change the value of the object isCompleted to !isCompleted so the findOne will just return the object

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But I just want to be sure that `findOneAndUpdate` is finding the object.

Comment: i already use it in add element to the array as well as deleting from it  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id },
    { $push: { tasks: { index: Date.now(), text, isCompleted: false } } }
  ) & User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id },
    { $pull: { tasks: { index: Number(req.params.index) } } }
  )